# Can we use same module.css file in different components in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-in-js

I'm a beginner in react recently I learnt about using module CSS for solving naming conflicts, now I want to refactor my app but in 2 component's I am using styles from same file.
I wanna know can I use that module.css file in both of my components?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

Just import your css module in all the components you want to use it in.

```js
import styles from '/your-css.module.css'
```